# How to keep the zeros on the left of numbers when converting a df to csv?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

let's say I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = c('01','02','03','04','05'))
```

when using the following function

```
write.csv(df,"df.csv")
```

the zeros are disappering and I don't want that. I want to keep the zeros and the variable x as character.

Comment: The zeros don't disappear in the resulting csv. Perhaps they are disappearing when you read them back in?

Comment: Have you tried opening the CSV as plain text file to confirm the absence of the zeros?

Comment: ah yeah sorry I think I know why. It's `write.csv2` function that made the error